# typescript react - define types for a element name anchor - TS2559

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying react with typescript,
on render. I need just insert an a element with name:

```
<a name='listStartups' />
```

then i need to use it with:

```
<a href="#listStartups" /></a>
```

but with first line, i get this typescript error:

TS2559: Type '{ name: String; }' has no properties in common with type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLAnchorElement'

anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `name` property for the `a` tag with HTML5. Use `id` instead.